# Unity : Changing color of 2D sprite distorts sprite shape

Tags: unity, sprites, color

In my 2D game, my circle shape for example, appears round, but when I change the color then it turns into a low poly circle with 8-16 points, more like a potato. Is there any way around this?

```
    myColor = new Color32 ((byte)colorR1, (byte)colorG2, (byte)colorB3, visibility);
    Color32 negativecolor = new Color32 ((byte)colorR1, (byte)colorG2, (byte)colorB3, (byte)(255-visibility));
    MaterialPropertyBlock props = new MaterialPropertyBlock ();
    props.SetColor ("_Color", myColor);
    rend.SetPropertyBlock (props);
    props.SetColor ("_Color", negativecolor);
    backchildrend.SetPropertyBlock (props);
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with this particular API, but my guess would be since you are newing the `MaterialPropertyBlock`, many of the settings are going to default. I'd suggest trying to manipulate the existing MPB from your shape (assuming that's possible).

Comment: This sounds rather strange. If you're still struggling with this, can you show us a screenshot of the symptoms, and a snippet of the shader you're using to draw these sprites?

Answer (score 0):

didn´t you try using the sprite renderer?
That´s how I changed the colors of sprites. Use

```
SpriteRenderer sprite = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
sprite.color = Color.red;
```

That should change the color of the whole sprite